Torch.io.read_image() Error. UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: 'libc10_cuda.so: cannot open shared object file
Running Ubuntu 22.04.4 on WSL2 with CUDA Version: 12.3
I'm trying to use torch.io to read in images in a conda environment, but torch.io is throwing an error.
I get the same error when trying to convert a PIL image using torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
    # conda env create -f thisfile.yaml
    name: epill2
    channels:
      - defaults
      - pytorch
      - nvidia
      - conda-forge

    dependencies:
      - python=3.9
      - numpy=1.26.4
      - cudatoolkit
      - pytorch=2.0.0
      - torchvision=0.15.0
      - torchaudio=2.0.0
      - pytorch-cuda=11.7
      - imgaug=0.4.0
      - ipykernel

    import torch
    import torchvision
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset

    class EPillDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self):        
            img_path = "./datasets/ePillID_data/classification_data/segmented_nih_pills_224/54868-6176_0_0.jpg"

            img = torchvision.io.read_image(img_path) # <-- error thrown here
            print(img.shape)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        EPillDataset()



I have some version of libjpeg installed already.
    dpkg -l | grep libjpeg outputs:

ii  libjpeg-turbo8:amd64              2.1.2-0ubuntu1                          amd64        IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.


ii  libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64          2.1.2-0ubuntu1                          amd64        Development files for the IJG JPEG library


ii  libjpeg8:amd64                    8c-2ubuntu10                            amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)

The libc10_cuda.so is not in my environment at ~/anaconda3/envs/epill2/lib
Does anyone know a fix? Do I need to compile TorchVision from source?
